# No adapter attached; skipping layout even though Layout is Inflated

Tags: android, android-layout

I am getting a error in Android logs "No adapter attached; skipping layout", even though the Layout is inflated with data and working fine, I might be due to messy code, can someone point me out where I am going wrong here, so that I can have it fixed.

Note : The app is working fine with no issues, I just wanted to figure out why I am getting the error No adapter attached; skipping layout in logs, maybe its due to the way I am calling the adapter after gettin JSON from my api.

Any insights will be very helpful.

> MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<DataAdapter> DataAdapterClassList;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;

    RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerViewlayoutManager;

    RecyclerView.Adapter recyclerViewadapter;

    ProgressBar progressBar;

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest ;

    ArrayList<String> BankNames;

    RequestQueue requestQueue ;

    String HTTP_SERVER_URL = "http://fyzahmed.com/testapi.php";

    View ChildView ;

    int RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DataAdapterClassList = new ArrayList<>();

        BankNames = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView1);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        recyclerViewlayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewlayoutManager);

        // JSON data web call function call from here.
        JSON_WEB_CALL();

        //RecyclerView Item click listener code starts from here.
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {

            GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {

                @Override public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                    return true;
                }

            });
            @Override
            public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

                ChildView = Recyclerview.findChildViewUnder(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                if(ChildView != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)) {

                    //Getting RecyclerView Clicked item value.
                    RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS = Recyclerview.getChildAdapterPosition(ChildView);

                    //Printing RecyclerView Clicked item clicked value using Toast Message.
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, BankNames.get(RecyclerViewClickedItemPOS), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView Recyclerview, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void JSON_WEB_CALL(){

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(HTTP_SERVER_URL,

                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                        JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(response);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }

    public void JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {

            DataAdapter GetDataAdapter2 = new DataAdapter();

            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);


                GetDataAdapter2.setBankName(json.getString("BANK"));

                //Adding subject name here to show on click event.
                BankNames.add(json.getString("BANK"));

            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            DataAdapterClassList.add(GetDataAdapter2);

        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        recyclerViewadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(DataAdapterClassList, this);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerViewadapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- You are binding your `adapter` to the recyclerView in a method called `JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL`
- The Method `JSON_PARSE_DATA_AFTER_WEBCALL` itself is called in
  `onResponse()` of your `JsonArrayRequest`

**So the process of binding an adapter to your RecyclerView is done when you get a response (This task must be taking too long to process)**

 This could be the reason why you're getting the error
Also,
This isn't a good way to bind an adapter to your recyclerView.
 
**I would suggest you to create an empty adapter first and then when you get the response update the adapter.**

Hope this helps you understand why you might be getting this error.